# Insert data into mysql table data from a FIFO pipe in linux continuously

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, named-pipes, mkfifo

I want to insert data from a fifo pipe into a mysql table, right now for me, this is possible until the fifo pipe process is killed,

the command :

```
$>mkfifo /path/to/pipe
$>sudo chmod 666 /path/to/pipe
$>find \ -sl > /path/to/pipe & msql db1 -e"LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/pipe' INTO TABLE T1 " &
```

the data in the fifo pipe is inserted until the process of mysql is down by kill process.

Is possible insert data without kill the process of the fifo pipe data in?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you mean you want the mysql command to keep running even after the find command finishes ?

Comment: maybe you can try the `sleep()` in mysql

Comment: No, I mean to write data simultaneously this is passing from the fifo pipe to mysql, i has been looking for a solution, I found the mysql:slurp, i am trying with this.

Comment: ajreal, sleep()? how this can help me?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like : $ mkfifo /path/to/pipe $ sudo chmod 666 /path/to/pipe $ tail -f /path/to/pipe | msql db1 & find \ -sl > /path/to/pipe & ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify @JulienPalard's comment above, you should be able to achieve your aim with the following commands.

(I use two different shell processes, whereas he uses one. For my description, try having both shells visible at once so that you can read output in one shell and write input in the other. If you know what you're doing, you can put the mysql process into the background and thus use only one shell.)

### Shell 1: output

```
$ mkfifo mypipe # create a named pipe
$ chmod 666 mypipe # Give all users read-write access to the pipe
$ tail -f mypipe | mysql -umyName -p mySchema # pipe mypipe into mysql
```

The last line above tells the named pipe to perpetually feed into the mysql process. Whenever you echo something into mypipe, it will be sent to  the mysql process as standard input.

After this, you won't get a new prompt because your `tail` command will run until you kill its process.

Keep this shell open and its `tail` process running while you use your other shell process (Shell 2: input) to send commands to `mysql`.

### Shell 2: input

```
$ echo 'show tables;' > mypipe # this will print output onto your *other* shell (Shell 1: output)
$ echo 'insert into mytable (1,2,3);' > mypipe # this performs an insertion
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the mysql system log report any errors?  I would look at http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/03/how-to-load-large-files-safely-into-innodb-with-load-data-infile/